# SQL Server job output to Azure blob storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, blob

Is there a way to redirect SQL Server Agent Job output directly to Azure blob storage instead of a shared folder for SQL Server hosted on an Azure VM?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no such facility available.

Comment: Hi Manveet Kaur, If the answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with @ Rishav Singh, we can not redirect SQL Server Agent Job output directly to Azure blob storage.

Any other ideas, you can using [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#upload-files) to upload output file to Azure blob :

```
azcopy copy '<local-directory-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>' --recursive
```

You can run this AzCopy command with [xp_cmdshell (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) in SSMS:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'azcopy copy '<local-directory-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>' --recursive'
```

Ref: [HOW TO: EXECUTE DOS COMMANDS FROM T-SQL](http://www.noelpulis.com/how-to-execute-dos-commands-from-t-sql/)

Hope this helps.